# How to read system variable with php file

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch the system variable that I have set through the Kubernetes yaml and need to read into php file that I have created. Somehow I am getting blank value.

I have set MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD over yaml file which is successfully reflect inside the container. Now I need to read those variable with the php file.So, I have created one env.php to confirm as below,

```
<?php
$db_host = getenv('MYSQL_HOST', true) ?: getenv('MYSQL_HOST');
$db_name = getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE', true) ?: getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE');
$db_user = getenv('MYSQL_USER', true) ?: getenv('MYSQL_USER');
$db_pwd  = getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD', true) ?: getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD');

echo "db_host: {$db_host}<br>";
echo "db_name: {$db_name}<br>";
echo "db_user: {$db_user}<br>";
echo "db_pwd: {$db_pwd}<br>"; 
?>
```

In this case, I am getting blank value as below

```
db_host:
db_name:
db_user:
db_pwd:
```

is there any other way that I can get those variable's value in PHP ?

Comment: I think thats too complicated. Try $db_host = getenv('MYSQL_HOST');

Comment: Why the curly brackets around the variables (echo statements)?

Comment: You should look for problems on the Kubernetes-yaml side. The code above is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing could be simpler, Watson:

```
$ Zumba=King php -r 'print_r(getenv("Zumba") . PHP_EOL);'
King
```

The second parameter does not mean what you think it does, but you can do this:

```
$ php -r 'print_r((getenv("Zumba") ?: "Queen") . PHP_EOL);'
Queen
```